# Unknown Syntax in Python script brings Index-Error. Can you read it? (and explain it?)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've found an old python script which doesn't run in Python3 nor Python2. However it should be valid functional code.

It generates some 3d-coordinates and pushes them in an array. Later it writes the array to file. Here an error occurs.

The array which contains data in the following form:

```
(Pdb) vertices
array([[ 0.00000000e+00,  3.74741921e-15,  6.50000000e+01],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  3.85844844e-15,  6.30132450e+01],
       [ 1.87370960e-15,  3.24536023e-15,  6.50000000e+01],
       [ 1.93591517e-15,  3.35310344e-15,  6.32317881e+01]])
```

The code-snippet is:

```
# Create the mesh
obj = mesh.Mesh(np.zeros(faces.shape[0], dtype=mesh.Mesh.dtype))
for i, f in enumerate(faces):
    for j in range(3):
        obj.vectors[i][j] = vertices[f[j],:]
```

The Error is:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Because I'm new in Python (I'm from PHP, C++)), I cannot really read/understand the addressing "vertices[f[j],:]". I thought to cast it as INT like "vertices[**int(f[j])**,:]" would fix it, but then the Geometry is also defective.

Please could anyone explain me this part of the Index-addressing?

**UPDATE:**
Yes, faces is an other 3-tuple vertex array.

```
(Pdb) p(f)
array([ 0., 26.,  2.])
(Pdb) p(j)
0
```

Hmm. Does the Statement "vertices[f[j],:]" mean take first and second value and ignore the third?? I still wonder the codes runs in the past.

Comment: What is `faces`? `i` and `j` are `int` values, so `f[j]` would seem to be the only value that might not be a valid index.

Comment: A very short explanation of the syntax: `vertices[f[j],:]` is equivalent to `vertices.__getitem__((f[j], slice())`. The comma-separated list of expressions is passed to `__getitem__` as a tuple, and the `:` is used to specify an instance of `slice`.

Comment: `faces` is most probable a 3-`tuple` of vertex indices that you want to select. `print` our `f[j]` and you see what it is, then you can decide what you need from the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older numpy versions accepted float numbers as indices to arrays. This was changed  in [numpy 1.12](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.12.0-notes.html#deprecationwarning-to-error), released in 2017. Now you have to provide integers.

With

```
f = np.array([ 0., 26.,  2.])
```

and `vertices` a 2-D arary, the code should be changed to `vertices[int(f[j]), :]` to select row number f[j]. Better, where `faces` is initialized, convert the entire array to int, for example `faces = np.array(..., dtype=int)` (replace ... by whatever the data needs to be).

You state: "The Geometry is also defective.". I don't know what you mean by that, but I'm sure that it is due to an unrelated problem.

You could try to run this in an older environment. I don't know what OS you're running; on Windows you can easily run an older version of Winpython without compromising your present installation. In Linux, you can install an older Anaconda distribution (don't try this in Windows unless you're very familiar with managing Anaconda environments).

If you want to know whether it is python2 or python3: python2 code can be recognized if any of these occur: `import exceptions`, `print 'without parentheses'`, `for i in xrange(n)`.